# Want to validate the width and height of each image in an multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, validation, file-upload, pdo

Hello I want to validate the width and height of each image that I upload as an array. Here is my code:

```
$photo_temp = array();
$photo_temp = $_FILES['photo']["tmp_name"];
$photo_temp = array_values(array_filter($photo_temp));
$other_temp = $_FILES['photo']["tmp_name"];

for($i=0;$i<count($photo);$i++)
{
 foreach ($other_temp as $single_file) {
 if(!empty($single_file)) {
 $photo_temp[$single_file] = getimagesize($single_file);
 $width2 = $photo_temp[$single_file][0];
 $height2 = $photo_temp[$single_file][1];
 }
}
print_r($photo_temp);
$my_ext1 = pathinfo( $photo[$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
if( $my_ext1=='jpg' || $my_ext1=='png' || $my_ext1=='jpeg' || $my_ext1=='gif' ) {
$final_name1[$m] = $z.'.'.$my_ext1;
                    move_uploaded_file($photo_temp[$i],"../assets/uploads/product_photos/".$final_name1[$m]);
$m++;
$z++;
}else if ($width2 > "300" || $height2 > "200") {
$valid = 0;
$error_message .= 'Image dimension should be within 300X200<br>';
 }
}
```

Here is the UI of how I'm aiming to do:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCOIk.png)

I want the error message to be sent if the image dimension is above 300 x 200 but the image kept on saving in the database even tho I had checked the error.

Comment: Your check for width and height is in the `else` part of the prior `if` statement -- so it will never run when you upload one of those image types.

Comment: @AlexHowansky should I put that check after if(!empty($single_file)) or under it?

Comment: What does this have to do with `mysql` and `pdo`?

Comment: Where is the code for the database ?

Comment: `$width2 > "300" || $height2 > "200"` - This is like comparing apples to oranges. The values of `$height2` and `$width2` are presumably integers whereas `"300"` and `"200"` are strings

Comment: You could do a lot of the work in Javascript before the file actually gets uploaded and then perform final validation on the server, do it all in javascript and accept some surprises or do it all on the server by uploading the files regardless.